# Is it possible to redirect a folder and a subfolder of that folder to different locations?

Tags: .htaccess

For examples.

/images to new-domain.com/images

and

/images/uploads/ to new-domain.com/uploads

Comment: maybe better also ask at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://new-domain.net/images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `R=301` means send the 301 HTTP status code (moved permanently).

[More RewriteEngine goodies](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html)

Comment: Thank you, Carson Myers. I'm trying to forward images to one location and a folder inside the images folder [uploads] to a different location. Only the images have changed location.

Comment: You should just be able to add another rewriterule, replacing `^images/(.*)$` with `^images/uploads/(.*)$`, and `http://new-domain.net/images/$1` with `http://new-domain.net/uploads/$1`. You may need to put that uploads one first. Try it out and see if it works, I'm not set up to test it at the moment.